# Release extensions with debug python?

Tags: python, windows, debugging

I am trying to debug a python application ([see previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23957796/3524756)) that is failing inside a multiprocessing fork on windows. It would be nice to step though the imp module find_module function, and I have built python (debug and release) from scratch. I run the app with the release build and put debug prints in imp, but I would rather step through the failing code and look at whatever occurs to me as I do so. The application requires a number of third party extensions and I don't have debug versions. Is there any way I can use release extensions with the debug python build? I know I could simply create a "release" python build with symbols and debug information, but I'm feeling lazy Today and would rather use an actual debug build, if I can.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. If this had been an answer, I would have accepted it...

Comment: Moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not likely to work. Debug and release builds can use very different C run-time libraries that won't play nice with each other when you try to use them in the same process (for example, attempting to free some release-allocated memory using the debug runtime may just crash or assert when it doesn't find the extra metadata it's expecting). To work with release modules, the safest thing is to use a release Python built with symbols.